# resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - Ionic Version 3.x

Tags: php, javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3

este é meu primeiro post por aqui, e espero que possam me ajudar.

Sou novo na área de desenvolvimento de aplicativos e estou começando a desenvolver uma aplicação em Ionic para meu TCC, cujo intuito é trazer as noticias do site oficial do câmpus IFSP - VOTUPORANGA, para o aplicativo para levar as noticias até mais próximo dos alunos, colaboradores e gestão. Por motivos éticos não tenho acesso direto a base de dados oficial, e terei que fazer acesso por um "web service" que simplesmente irá puxar os dados do banco, converter em JSON e eu terei que ler o JSON e mostrar na tela. Eu recebi uma "cópia" sem dados sensíveis do banco e tive que encontrar a tabela responsável pelas notícias mostradas e tentar eu mesmo fazer a parte que converte em JSON e para testar se realmente funcionou precisava testar em local e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

[image: Imagem descritiva do problema]

E bom os códigos relacionados as páginas necessárias para fazer isso. Vale ressaltar que eu testei e apresente pra "pré-banca" uma versão que puxada de uma API, chamada themoviedb, para mostrar que era possível a minha ideia e ter permissão de continuidade da pesquisa.

Segue os códigos:
noticia.ts -> é um provider ionic

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

home.ts -> é a pagina de typscript de onde deveria ser inserido se tudo desse certo os dados
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

home.html -> é a página onde é exibido

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero que possam me ajudar!

Comment: Prefira postar texto ao invés de imagens. Assim, outras pessoas poderão copiar o texto e fazer testes e experimentos em busca de uma resposta à pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o seu backend está negando essa requisição pelo fato dela estar rodando em localhost.
Você precisa habilitar CORS no header da sua chamada no php:

> https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Basicamente você irá inserir o comando:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

No header do seu backend para que ele passe a aceitar determinadas chamadas de um link diferente.